# how get last tag test via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get last button text via JQuery. You can see my html tag and js code which I have tried but not result.

**HTML**

```
<div id="pagedata">
   <ul id="paginationIda"  class="pagination">
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">1</button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">2</button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">3</button></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
 var lastli =   $('#paginationIda li:last-child').val();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to retrieve the `text` from the `button`.
The updated selector would look like: `var lastli =   $('#paginationIda li:last-child button').text();`

If you want it as a Number instead of String then simply use
 `var lastli = Number($('#paginationIda li:last-child').text());`

According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/) `val()` doesn't seem appropriate here.

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.

```js
var lastli =   $('#paginationIda li:last-child button').text();
var lastli_asNo = Number($('#paginationIda li:last-child').text());
console.log(lastli);
console.log(lastli_asNo );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pagedata">
   <ul id="paginationIda"  class="pagination">
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">1</button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">2</button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">3</button></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: thx, its worked.  and one more question : i want to use this html to generate next li  in size this html with unique id : sample  if i will get 3 then i  will use this value to generate ul  with 3 li tag and every li must be unique id. could you advice how to do it?.

Comment: I would ask that as a separate question [Stackoverflow prefers one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post). I'll start on a solution though.

Comment: @IslamIsmayilov simply use a for loop from 1 to that number and use the current iteration as a prefix or suffix (eg my_li_1) etc and append to DOM

Answer (score 1):

You should get the text from button, you can use [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and replace val by [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Try this code:

```
var lastli =   $('#paginationIda li:last-child').find("button").text();
```

**Result:** https://jsfiddle.net/8adjy67y/

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastli = $('#paginationIda li:last-child').text();
```

will return a String value . 3 in this case.
If you want it as a number use:

```
var lastli = Number($('#paginationIda li:last-child').text());
```